# How to use bicseq2 with human genome hg38?

Tags: genome

all

Recently I want to use bicseq2 to analyze my data with genome hg38. But the official website https://compbio.med.harvard.edu/BIC-seq/ didn't offer the mappability files with hg38. So I try to generate the mappability files with method followed by https://github.com/ding-lab/BICSEQ2.

The mappability files generation and bicseq2-norm succeed, but bicseq2-norm failed.
The error command is `/lustre/home/xx/xx/CNV_analysis/software/NBICseq-seg_v0.7.2/combineFile/combineFile /lustre/home/xx/xx/CNV_analysis/2.call_CNV_BICseq2/test_fa/ICC51/norm_out/chr1.norm.bin | /lustre/home/xx/xx/CNV_analysis/software/NBICseq-seg_v0.7.2/MBIC-seq_v0.1.5/MBICseq -l 50.493`
The error code is "key not found".

Is there anyone know the reason or how to use bicseq2 with hg38 correctly?

A solution of error code or a pipeline to use bicseq2 with hg38.